# Leave only first 50 records in SQL database and delete the rest

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have a table of scores, which is made of 2 fields: *name* and *high score*. Something like this:

```
----------------------- 
| name     | score    |
-----------------------
| John     | 2450     |
-----------------------
| Alice    | 2420     |
-----------------------
                         ... etc
```

I need to *delete* all the rows till the top 50 scores.

Is it possible without creating another temporary table ?

Comment: loop through all the rows deleting the lowest score until there are 50 scores left.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

please try this

```
delete from scores_tbl Where
id not in
(select * from
(select id from scores_tbl order by score desc limit 50)
 as temp)
```

Comment: I added the IDs, like @ling.s suggested and with your code it works exactly as i wanted to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create an auto increment field

```
alter table scores add id int unique auto_increment not null;
```

This will automatically number your rows in the order of a select query without conditions or order-by

```
select * scores;
delete from scores where id > 50;
```

Finally, remove that field

```
alter table scores drop id;
```

Comment: That gives ids to the database, but doesnt correspond with the highscores. The row with id=1, is the first inserted row, not the row with the highest score.

Answer (score 0):

You need a unique field for this , so either alter the table before and after the delete.

Like :
**alter table scores add id int unique auto_increment not null;**

**delete from scores where id > 50;**

**alter table drop column id;**

Comment: for last line :mysql do not allow the target table name in the inner query(it gives error while executing )