# How do I delete a row if there are 4 or more rows named after the username

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

My professor wants us to create a web-based comment system wherein a user can send up to 3 comments, if the user decides to create another one when he already has 3 comments named after him on the database, the program should delete the oldest one and save the new one.

What I thought about was to fetch the rows named after the user and if it is greater or equal to 4, I should delete the row where username = session user and insert the new record. Although this was just in theory, is this the best way to go about this? Do you guys have any other suggestions? How exactly do I pick the rows to remove? Do I base it off the highest comment_id?

Comment: Store the date/time the comment was made, delete the oldest based on that.

Comment: The most common way to implement this in a database would use a trigger.

Comment: @Bulk Ah yes, I actually was about to edit this when I realized I should create a date column and use now when inserting it on the database. But still, thanks for the answer

Comment: @GordonLinoff Interesting, I heard about triggers while I was studying database. I guess I have to search about "how to restrict number of rows using triggers". Thank you, I'll be back.

Comment: @CarlDun Are you sure you have to delete it, and not just make sure it shows the most recent 3 comments? Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @Loko Yeah, I think he gave us a bad example on trying to limit stuff on the database since a comment in its nature, should show every possible ones like on youtube. His argument was there might be an event where there would be spammers or remove ones that aren't useful anymore since you decided to create a newer one.

Comment: @CarlDun Read the answer I provided. It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read: [Leave only first 50 records in SQL database and delete the rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255578/leave-only-first-50-records-in-sql-database-and-delete-the-rest)

So basically do this:

Create an Auto Increment Id with the comments.
Then:

```
DELETE FROM comments
WHERE
  id NOT IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT id
      FROM comments
      ORDER BY date
      desc LIMIT 3) s
  )
```

Comment: I don't know if this is a stupid question but, what does the s do?

Comment: Oh and I stuck with the id since the user's date might get messed up due to a bad battery or something so I made sure all the recent ones should stay.

Answer (score 1):

Do not delete the rows in the database, just do a limit 0,4 on your select query
with a order by on a create date